# d3.js voronoi event. Mouseover seems to disappear when cursor is exactly above point

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouseevent, mouseover, voronoi

What am I doing wrong here please? I want to increase the point size when the mouse enters the associated voronoi cell, however the point goes back to its original size when the mouse is exaclty above that point; I have tried both the `mouseover` and `mousemove` events without any luck. Code in snippet, you can zoom in and you will be able to see what I just described.
Many thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Chart</title>


<!-- Reference minified version of D3 -->
<script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
    <style>
        .grid line {
            stroke: #ddd;
        }
    </style>


<div id='scatter-plot'>
<svg width="700" height="500">
</svg>
</div>

   
<script>

            var data = [];
                for (let i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
                data.push({
                    x: Math.random(),
                    y: Math.random(),
                    dotNum: i,
                })
            }
                
        renderChart(data)
 
    

        
function renderChart(data) {

    var totalWidth = 920,
        totalHeight = 480;
    
    var margin = {
            top: 10,
            left: 50,
            bottom: 30,
            right: 0
        }
    
    var width = totalWidth  - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = totalHeight  - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // inner chart dimensions, where the dots are plotted
//    var width = width - margin.left - margin.right;
//    var height = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
     var tsn = d3.transition().duration(200);

    // radius of points in the scatterplot
    var pointRadius = 2;

    var extent = {
        x: d3.extent(data, function (d) {return d.x}),
        y: d3.extent(data, function (d) {return d.y}),
    };

    var scale = {
        x: d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]),
        y: d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
    };

    var axis = {
        x: d3.axisBottom(scale.x).ticks(xTicks).tickSizeOuter(0),
        y: d3.axisLeft(scale.y).ticks(yTicks).tickSizeOuter(0),
    };
    
    var gridlines = {
        x: d3.axisBottom(scale.x).tickFormat("").tickSize(height),
        y: d3.axisLeft(scale.y).tickFormat("").tickSize(-width),
    }
    

    var colorScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 1]).range(['#06a', '#06a']);

    // select the root container where the chart will be added
    var container = d3.select('#scatter-plot');

    var zoom = d3.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([1, 20])
        .on("zoom", zoomed);
    
    var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
        .attr("id", "tooltip")
        .style("opacity", 0);

    // initialize main SVG
    var svg = container.select('svg')
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .call(zoom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
    // Clip path
    svg.append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);


    // Heatmap dots
    var dotsGroup = svg.append("g")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
        .append("g");
    
    //Create X axis
    var renderXAxis = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")

    //Create Y axis
    var renderYAxis = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")


    // set up axis generating functions
    var xTicks = Math.round(width / 50);
    var yTicks = Math.round(height / 50);

    
    function updateScales(data, scale){
        scale.x.domain([extent.x[0], extent.x[1]]).nice(),
        scale.y.domain([extent.y[0], extent.y[1]]).nice()
    }

    function zoomed() {
        d3.event.transform.x = d3.event.transform.x;
        d3.event.transform.y = d3.event.transform.y;

        // update: rescale x axis
        renderXAxis.call(axis.x.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleX(scale.x)));
        renderYAxis.call(axis.y.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleX(scale.y)));


        dotsGroup.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
    }
    
    // add the overlay on top of everything to take the mouse events
    dotsGroup.append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'overlay')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height)
        .style('fill', 'red')
        .style('opacity', 0)
        .on('mouseover', mouseMoveHandler)
        .on('mouseleave', () => {
            // hide the highlight circle when the mouse leaves the chart
            highlight(null);
    });
    
    renderPlot(data);
    
    function renderPlot(data){
        updateScales(data, scale);
        
        svg.select('.y.axis')
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + -pointRadius + " 0)" )
            .call(axis.y);
        
        var h = height + pointRadius;
        svg.select('.x.axis')
            .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + h + ")")
            .call(axis.x);
        
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "grid")
            .call(gridlines.x);
        
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "grid")
            .call(gridlines.y);
        
        
        //Do the chart
        var update = dotsGroup.selectAll("circle").data(data)
        
        update
            .enter()
            .append('circle')
            .attr('r', pointRadius)
            .attr('cx', d => scale.x(d.x))
            .attr('cy', d => scale.y(d.y))
            .attr('fill', d => colorScale(d.y))
    };


    // create a voronoi diagram 
    var voronoiDiagram = d3.voronoi()
        .x(d => scale.x(d.x))
        .y(d => scale.y(d.y))
        .size([width, height])(data);


    // add a circle for indicating the highlighted point
    dotsGroup.append('circle')
        .attr('class', 'highlight-circle')
        .attr('r', pointRadius*2) // increase the size if highlighted
        .style('fill', 'red')
        .style('display', 'none');

    // callback to highlight a point
    function highlight(d) {
        // no point to highlight - hide the circle and the tooltip
        if (!d) {
            d3.select('.highlight-circle').style('display', 'none');
            //tooltip.style("opacity",0);
            // otherwise, show the highlight circle at the correct position
        } else {
            d3.select('.highlight-circle')
                .style('display', '')
                .style('stroke', colorScale(d.y))
                .attr('cx', scale.x(d.x))
                .attr('cy', scale.y(d.y));
        }
    }

    // callback for when the mouse moves across the overlay
    function mouseMoveHandler() {
        // get the current mouse position
        var [mx, my] = d3.mouse(this);

        var site = voronoiDiagram.find(mx, my);

        // highlight the point if we found one, otherwise hide the highlight circle
        highlight(site && site.data);


        for (let i = 0; i < site.data.dotNum; i++) {
            //do something....
        }
        
    }




}



    
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- you have to draw the `overlay` rect after the circles and the highlight circle. If not then hovering over a circle generates a mouse leave event and you see a flashing of the highlight circle
- use the `mousemove` event not the `mouseover`, that is kind of a **mouse-enter** event
- I have added logic to only update the highlight when it changes dots
- the grid is not updated on zoom and translate (not fixed)
- even when moving over the `overlay` there were still `mouseleave` events - they where caused by the grid lines. Moved the dots group after the grid line groups

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Chart</title>


<!-- Reference minified version of D3 -->
<script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
<style>
.grid line { stroke: #ddd; }
</style>

<div id='scatter-plot'>
<svg width="700" height="500">
</svg>
</div>

<script>

var data = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    data.push({
        x: Math.random(),
        y: Math.random(),
        dotNum: i,
    })
}
renderChart(data);

function renderChart(data) {

    var totalWidth = 920,
        totalHeight = 480;

    var margin = {
            top: 10,
            left: 50,
            bottom: 30,
            right: 0
        }

    var width = totalWidth  - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = totalHeight  - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // inner chart dimensions, where the dots are plotted
//    var width = width - margin.left - margin.right;
//    var height = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

     var tsn = d3.transition().duration(200);

    // radius of points in the scatterplot
    var pointRadius = 2;

    var extent = {
        x: d3.extent(data, function (d) {return d.x}),
        y: d3.extent(data, function (d) {return d.y}),
    };

    var scale = {
        x: d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]),
        y: d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
    };

    var axis = {
        x: d3.axisBottom(scale.x).ticks(xTicks).tickSizeOuter(0),
        y: d3.axisLeft(scale.y).ticks(yTicks).tickSizeOuter(0),
    };
    
    var gridlines = {
        x: d3.axisBottom(scale.x).tickFormat("").tickSize(height),
        y: d3.axisLeft(scale.y).tickFormat("").tickSize(-width),
    }

    var colorScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 1]).range(['#06a', '#06a']);

    // select the root container where the chart will be added
    var container = d3.select('#scatter-plot');

    var zoom = d3.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([1, 20])
        .on("zoom", zoomed);

    var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
        .attr("id", "tooltip")
        .style("opacity", 0);

    // initialize main SVG
    var svg = container.select('svg')
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .call(zoom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // Clip path
    svg.append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    //Create X axis
    var renderXAxis = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")

    //Create Y axis
    var renderYAxis = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")

    // set up axis generating functions
    var xTicks = Math.round(width / 50);
    var yTicks = Math.round(height / 50);

    function updateScales(data, scale){
        scale.x.domain([extent.x[0], extent.x[1]]).nice(),
        scale.y.domain([extent.y[0], extent.y[1]]).nice()
    }

    function zoomed() {
        d3.event.transform.x = d3.event.transform.x;
        d3.event.transform.y = d3.event.transform.y;

        // update: rescale x axis
        renderXAxis.call(axis.x.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleX(scale.x)));
        renderYAxis.call(axis.y.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleX(scale.y)));

        dotsGroup.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
    }

    var dotsGroup;
    renderPlot(data);

    function renderPlot(data){
        updateScales(data, scale);
        
        svg.select('.y.axis')
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + -pointRadius + " 0)" )
            .call(axis.y);
        
        var h = height + pointRadius;
        svg.select('.x.axis')
            .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + h + ")")
            .call(axis.x);
        
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "grid")
            .call(gridlines.x);
        
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "grid")
            .call(gridlines.y);

        dotsGroup = svg.append("g")
                       .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
                       .append("g");
        
        //Do the chart
        var update = dotsGroup.selectAll("circle").data(data)
        
        update
            .enter()
            .append('circle')
            .attr('r', pointRadius)
            .attr('cx', d => scale.x(d.x))
            .attr('cy', d => scale.y(d.y))
            .attr('fill', d => colorScale(d.y))
    };

    // create a voronoi diagram 
    var voronoiDiagram = d3.voronoi()
        .x(d => scale.x(d.x))
        .y(d => scale.y(d.y))
        .size([width, height])(data);

    // add a circle for indicating the highlighted point
    dotsGroup.append('circle')
        .attr('class', 'highlight-circle')
        .attr('r', pointRadius*2) // increase the size if highlighted
        .style('fill', 'red')
        .style('display', 'none');

    // add the overlay on top of everything to take the mouse events
    dotsGroup.append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'overlay')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height)
        .style('fill', 'red')
        .style('opacity', 0)
        .on('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler)
        .on('mouseleave', () => {
            // hide the highlight circle when the mouse leaves the chart
            console.log('mouse leave');
            highlight(null);
    });

    var prevHighlightDotNum = null;
    // callback to highlight a point
    function highlight(d) {
        // no point to highlight - hide the circle and the tooltip
        if (!d) {
            d3.select('.highlight-circle').style('display', 'none');
            prevHighlightDotNum = null;
            //tooltip.style("opacity",0);
            // otherwise, show the highlight circle at the correct position
        } else {
            if (prevHighlightDotNum !== d.dotNum) {
                d3.select('.highlight-circle')
                  .style('display', '')
                  .style('stroke', colorScale(d.y))
                  .attr('cx', scale.x(d.x))
                  .attr('cy', scale.y(d.y));
                prevHighlightDotNum = d.dotNum;
            }
        }
    }

    // callback for when the mouse moves across the overlay
    function mouseMoveHandler() {
        // get the current mouse position
        var [mx, my] = d3.mouse(this);

        var site = voronoiDiagram.find(mx, my);

        //console.log('site', site);
        // highlight the point if we found one, otherwise hide the highlight circle
        highlight(site && site.data);

        for (let i = 0; i < site.data.dotNum; i++) {
            //do something....
        }
    }
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a million!! That is fantastic!! And thanks for pointing out the events caused by the grid lines, I was totally unaware of this. I owe you a beer (or maybe a truck of beers, that sounds fairer...)